# macos x terminal cursor is 1 posisiton righter then it should be

Tags: terminal

When I start terminal the cursor position is 1 position righter then it should be and there is a gap between last symbol and the cursor.

How can I fix it?

Comment: A screenshot could be helpful. You could use http://tinypic.com/ for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"1 position righter then it should be" is a matter of opinion :-) I believe the cursor is right where it should be. But either way, this is determined by the `PS1` environment variable (assuming you're using the default bash shell)

You'll want to set `PS1` to not have a training space on the end of it. The exact command will depend on what your `PS1` is currently. The following should get you there:

```
echo $PS1
```

Will show you what `PS1` currently is. Copy that value, then execute:

```
export PS1="<paste value>"
```

Pasting the value you copied in place of `<paste value>`. Be sure to not have a training space. So in my case, I did:

```
export PS1="\h:\W \u\$"
```

To make this stick, add the `export PS1` line to your `.bashrc` file with a text editor.

Comment: Glad I could help!